# Security implications of client side authentication with a remote database

Tags: authentication, databases, desktop

I'm developing a desktop app for use internal to my company.  The app's installation file is located on our company server and therefore is only accessible to authenticated employees (under the assumption our network is secure).  If I were to connect to a remote database (such as AWS), would that pose a risk to exposing information?

Comment: That depends on your threat model. What kind of information are you worried about exposing?

Comment: Specifically the information stored in the database.

Comment: This is really hard to answer cause it depends. It depends on the network connection to the DB, where and how the DB is stored, and the authentication on the DB. You also should ask yourself, is it possible for a user to copy the installation files outside of the corp. network? All these things play into the amount of risk you're exposing the company to.

Comment: It is possible that a user could steal the installation files but that would be an insider threat and violation of company policy which for my situation would be a whole different issue.  To clarify some of the other details, the database connection would be through Oracle client software which I believe uses TCP.  The database would be reside on a reputable third party server (like AWS) and user authentication would be performed prior to connection to the remote database.